# Como colocar a data e hora atual num campo do tipo datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Eu tenho um campo `date` em uma tabela que é do tipo `datetime` e quero lá colocar a data atual do meu servidor.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Já tentei de tudo, com `NOW()` no SQL de inserção, mas depois vi que não funciona. Já tentei alterar o `DEFAULT` do campo `date` para `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` e nada.

No PHP já tentei com a função `date`, e `gmdate`,

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

e continuo a ter `0000-00-00 00:00:00` na base de dados, isto quado tento inserir um registo na tabela.

Comment: e se antes você setar date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); o que acontece?

Comment: Já tentou definir seu campo assim? `date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),`

Comment: Qual a versão do seu MySQL ? Tente usar `Current_Date`.

Comment: Eu encontrei esse post: http://optimize-this.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/datetime-default-now-finally-available.html. O que fazemos geralmente é deixar o campo tipo `timestamp` e aí sim usar o `current_timestamp` ou `now()` como **default**.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza `ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for 'date'`

Comment: @Zoom é `MySQL 5.1.73`. Pois mas eu queria que fosse `datetime`.

Comment: @JorgeB. mostra a estrutura da sua tabela

Comment: @psantos está feito.

Comment: @JorgeB. primeira dica: mude o nome do campo `date` para `data` ou `my_date`. `date` é um tipo para MySQL logo haverá confusão

Comment: @psantos tens razão foi só uma experiência. E já descobri o problema, estou a usar `mysqli_` e estava a usar o 'i' como tipo de parâmetro e tem de ser 's'.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, não sei se é exactamente isso isso que eu entendi. Suponhamos que tens a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`tasks` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Para inserir um registo com a data actual do servidor, basta o seguinte comando:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (created_at) VALUES (now());
```

> mysql> select * from tasks;
>   +----+---------------------+
>   | id | created_at          |
>   +----+---------------------+
>   |  1 | 2016-01-19 11:49:58 |
>   +----+---------------------+
>   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Usando o PHP (com PDO), basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php

// algo mais ou menos como: 2016-01-19 11:56:30
$data_actual = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$sql = "INSET INTO tasks(created_at) VALUES (:created_at)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':created_at', $data_actual);
$stmt->execute();
```

## UPDATE:

Nota: Pelo erro, estás a tentar adicionar um valor do tipo `datetime` num campo do tipo `date`

## UPDATE 2:

Pela estrutura da tabela, o campo no nome `date` está ou poderá causar problemas.
Mude o nome deste campo. Pois `date` é usado como um tipo de dados do MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Depois de fazeres esta actualização, podes fazer o insert desta forma:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (created_at) VALUES (now());
```